# Iterate 2D list from a given point (x,y)

Tags: python, list, loops

I have a 2D list (matrix) in which I want apply a function to all elements after a certain position, or perform some search.

Example: Starting from the point `(1,2)` in the list

```
[
 [1,2,3,4]
 [5,6,7,8]
 [9,10,11,12]
]
```

means that we want to start iterating from the number `7` and skip the first row and the first two elements from the second row.

I can just start from the beginning and check when I am ahead of the element at point (x,y) and just do nothing before, but basically the idea is to save some iterating cycles if the 2D list (matrix) is bigger.

I've tried changing the iterating variables for the first iteration (like I would in C++ for example), but that failed:

```python
flag = True
for i in range(height):
    for j in range(width):
        if flag:
            i = x
            j = y
            flag = False
        ...
```

Comment: What exactly does "from" mean in a 2D matrix?

Comment: "From" a given point, for example from the point (0,1) (row 0 , column 1) should mean that we skip the very first element on index (0,0), I'll edit the question with example

Comment: Sample inputs and outputs will get more help. It's just too vague...

Comment: @DanielHao, I added an example, also the last piece of code that I tried would work in C++ with normal loops. I can provide working c++ code if it would make things clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This script apply a function (print) to all elements after the starting_i and starting_j coordinates.

```
m = [[1,2,3,4], [5,6,7,8,9], [10,11,12,13]]

starting_i = 1
starting_j = 2
for i in range(starting_i, len(m)):
    for j in range(starting_j, len(m[i])):
        # apply your function here
        print(m[i][j])
    starting_j = 0
```

Output:

7
8
9
10
11
12
13

Comment: This works - if the `starting position` is known ahead of time.

Answer (score 1):

Your method fails because `i = x` and `j = y` will only work for that iteration (the ith or the jth). Then they are going to be switched to the next number in `range`

Even though you could still achieve this with your `if flag` I present you a more convenient method, list slicing. If you have a list `a = [1, 2, 3, 4]` then `a[2:]` will return `[3, 4]`

So you can apply this for your `2D` list in the following way

```
a = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [6, 7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12, 13]]
startRow = 1
startCol = 2

for col in a[startRow][startCol:]: # You only need to slice the `startRow`
    print(col)

for row in a[startRow+1:]: # Now loop through all the remaining rows starting at the next row of startRow
    for col in row:
        print(col)
```

Comment: Isn't slicing adding to the time complexity though?

Comment: @donkihott  Considering that it has to create a new list for each "sliced" one, it probably has an impact that may be visible with larger sizes. `range` is also created each time, but is faster and different from a `list`.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through the remainder of the incomplete row, then resume iterating through the complete rows starting at i + 1 as follows:

```
def iterate_from(i,j):
    for k in range(j, width):
        perform(i,k)
    for l in range(i+1, height)
        for k in range(width):
            perform(l,k)
```